# How to unwrap a stone house without seams at the corners?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I want to create an old house with stone walls but I don't want any visible seams on the outside so that the stone texture goes around the corner.

Does anyone know how to do that? Where do I have to place the seams? I couldn't find anything helpful so far.

Comment: the image shows the smart uv project btw.

Comment: Since the image texture is of a flat wall I'm not sure how you expect to do that! If you use seams you can move the UV islands around to get the best match on the corners.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your texture image is repeatable, you'll necessarily have a seam between at least 2 walls, but I guess you have 2 solutions:

- Either scale the UV until you find the exact size that will allow the 2 parts to join without seam:

[image]

- Or you could use the *Clone* brush (or the *Stencil* option of the *Draw* brush) in order to paint some stones where you want the seam to disappear:

[image]